# PowerPoint JS API: connect 2 rectangles

Tags: office-js, office-addins

I can't find any reference on how to connect 2 shapes in PowerPoint using their JS API for Office Add-in (using latest version as of 03.2024).

Here is my simple code:

```
export async function run() {
  await PowerPoint.run(async (context) => {
    const shapes = 
    context.presentation.slides.getItemAt(0).shapes; // Get the first slide

    // Create rectangle 1
    const rectangle1 =  shapes.addGeometricShape(PowerPoint.GeometricShapeType.rectangle);
    rectangle1.left = 100;
    rectangle1.top = 50;
    rectangle1.height = 150;
    rectangle1.width = 50;
    rectangle1.name = "Rectangle1";

    // Create rectangle 2
    const rectangle2 = shapes.addGeometricShape(PowerPoint.GeometricShapeType.rectangle);
    rectangle2.left = 300;
    rectangle2.top = 50;
    rectangle2.height = 150;
    rectangle2.width = 100;
    rectangle2.name = "Rectangle2";

    const line = shapes.addLine(
    PowerPoint.ConnectorType.straight, 
    { left: 150, 
      top: 125, 
      height: -1 /**another great move MS! why 0 is not working?**/, 
      width: 150 
    });
    line.name = "StraightLine";

    await context.sync();
  });
}
```

[Result of this code](https://jmp.sh/VhHkIoHC) and [How it should be](https://jmp.sh/3p5Pmonp)

What do I mean by connecting - [link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/draw-or-delete-a-line-or-connector-f304ef73-9514-450b-9bb9-28c6057020f2)

How do I connect them with a line?

Comment: It looks like you can't do this currently. Great job, microsoft!

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "connect". You can't do anything programmatically that an end user can't do manually. How would you manually "connect" two rectangles?

Comment: @RickKirkham I would draw a line from one anchor point of a rectangle to another anchor point of another rectangle. If you want, I can add a picture

Answer (score 0):

Use the [ShapeCollection.addLine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/powerpoint/powerpoint.shapecollection#powerpoint-powerpoint-shapecollection-addline-member(1)) method. Here's an example:

```
// This function gets the collection of shapes on the first slide,
// and adds a line to the collection, while specifying its
// start and end points. Then it names the shape.
await PowerPoint.run(async (context) => {
const shapes = context.presentation.slides.getItemAt(0).shapes;

// For a line, left and top are the coordinates of the start point,
// while height and width are the coordinates of the end point.
const line = shapes.addLine(PowerPoint.ConnectorType.straight, 
  { 
    left: 400, 
    top: 200, 
    height: 20, 
    width: 150 
  });
line.name = "StraightLine";

await context.sync();
});
```

Comment: Yes, this methods just adds line, it does not connect shapes. [Connecting shapes manually|https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/office/video-connect-shapes-df788cce-2efa-4b52-baaf-8c2d38881b33#:~:text=move%20a%20shape.-,Select%20Home%20%3E%20Connector.,when%20the%20shapes%20are%20connected.]

Comment: Have you tried setting the left, top, height, and width properties so that one end of the line is exactly on the edge of a shape and the other end is exactly on the edge of the other shape? If so, please edit your code in the original question to show how you have tried this.

Comment: yes, I've tried it, and it just adds line, but does not connect them. Based on my comment from 2024-03-27 16:30 - do you understand what I want to achieve?

Comment: Is updated question is more clear now @RickKirkham?

Comment: When I run your code, it works. The line seems to be connected. If I add a second line manually, the two lines are connected in exactly the same way. This might not be evident visually at first, but if you select the line that's added programmatically you can see the little white circles where it intersects with the two rectangles. Your link to how to connect shapes is for Visio, not PowerPoint. Your two links for "Result ..." and "How it should be ..." are both broken, do I can't tell what you are seeing.